# multiple views with multiple rails layouts for multiple head scripts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, layout

I want each of my view files to have their own layout because each one needs different stuff in their `<head>` tags with different scripts being run but they should still inherit the same stuff from `layouts/application.html.erb`. Is this possible?

layouts/application.html.erb -> layouts/a.html.erb -> views/a.index.html.erb

layouts/application.html.erb -> layouts/b.html.erb -> views/b.index.html.erb

Comment: What's wrong with using `<% content_for :header_tags do %>`?

Comment: Wouldn't that put it in the body tho?

Answer (score 1):

`content_for :header_tags` is for adding extra lines to the `<head>` of your `application.html.erb` or `base.html.erb`. Here's a live example from `whatever.html.erb`:

```
<% content_for :header_tags do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :redmine_helpdesk, :plugin => 'redmine_contacts_helpdesk'  %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :helpdesk, :plugin => 'redmine_contacts_helpdesk' %>
<% end %>
```

Then the `base.html.erb` calls `<%= yield :header_tags -%>` to express whatever was stored with the :header_tags key.